# Do html tags have numbers in spec?

Tags: html

just wondering, I need a numbered way of identifying certain HTML tags. Now I could do this in an arbitrary way myself but would rather use whatever official table I can find. So, my question is: Is there an official numbered list of HTML tags like some periodic table of them (bad example?) in official or sudo-official documentation?

Comment: Can you more clearly describe your goals and what problems you're having? HTML tags already have an identifier - the tag name itself. Why must you use numbers? I can't understand what you're after and I have doubts that anyone else will either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HTML4 spec has an [official list of elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/index/elements.html)

The HTML5 spec also has an [official list of elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/index.html#elements-1)

And, people have written an [unofficial periodic table](http://joshduck.com/periodic-table.html) containing the HTML5 elements, but of course that's a little tongue in cheek

Comment: Hah, you even got me a periodic table. You sir, are the (explosive) rubix cube.

Comment: @Gareth, Periodic table «no longer available» by supplied URL(

Answer (score 1):

I haven't ever seen anything but the tag name used in the HTML 4 and HTML 5 specs. Occasionally various sections in a language spec will be referenced by number, but for HTML the tag name is a strong enough identifier in nearly any scenario. Why make it ambiguous by abstracting that?

http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/#auto-toc-4

Comment: You see, I have a program that will work with DOM tags a lot, I wanted  to retrieve (lets just say) wrappers for instance. Storing them all as objects in an array is much cheaper and easier than storing them in object by name.

Comment: @TERMtm - That makes sense. However, in that scenario a hashtable would be superior to an array for rapid lookup since it doesn't require O(n) operations to find the item. You could use either integers or strings as the keys.